# Use URL to jump to a page in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, apache

My website structure is as follows:

```
public_html/
    - index.php
    - students.php
```

The user loads the site (index.php) which contains a button. When this button is clicked AJAX is used to load "students.php" and it is displayed to the user (As if they just went to a different page seamlessly). When doing so the following JavaScript is run:

```
var state = {'Page' : 'Students'};
history.pushState(state, null, "students");
```

This adds a state to the browsers history and causes the browsers URL to display "example.com/students" instead of "example.com". However if a user was to refresh at this point, nothing would load (404 Not Found) due to the folder "students" not actually existing.

My question is, how can I get the users browser to actually display "index.php" and automatically take them to the students page. In other words, the user refreshes "example.com/students" and what actually happens is the user is taken to the index.php file and the AJAX automatically takes them to the students page (As though they actually refreshed the page)

Note: I am aware I can pass null to the url parameter in "pushState()" however this URL behaviour is desired as it would allow users to quickly jump to a page (If I can get it working)

The full code to show the students page via AJAX is as follows:

```
/**
 * Display students screen.
 */
 function displayStudents(createState) {
     if(typeof(createState)==='undefined') {
         createState = true;
     }

     $("#container").css("width", $( window ).width());
     $("#container").css("position", "fixed");
     $("#container").animate({marginLeft: "-100%"}, ANIMATION_SPEED);

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             $("#container").css("margin-left", "100%");
             $("#container").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
             $("#container").animate({marginLeft: "0"}, ANIMATION_SPEED, null, function reset() {
             $("#container").css("width", "100%");
             $("#container").css("position", "relative");
         });

         if(createState) {
             var state = {'Page' : 'Students'};
             history.pushState(state, null, "students");
         }
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "students.php", true);
    setTimeout(function() { xmlhttp.send(); }, ANIMATION_SPEED);
}
```

Most of the code here is for animation.

Comment: what js is the button actually running to show students.php?

Comment: you can use an `.htaccess` file for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words, the user refreshes "example.com/students" and what actually happens is the user is taken to the index.php file and the AJAX automatically takes them to the students page (As though they actually refreshed the page)

The point of pushState is that when you use JavaScript to transform the state of the page, you provide a URL which the server can use to deliver some HTML that will provide the page *in that state*.

If you are always going to serve up the homepage and then transform it with JavaScript, then just use [hashbangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs). `pushState` is entirely the wrong tool for the job.

If you were to use pushState, then a pseudocode implementation of a possible approach would be along the lines of:

```
GET data needed for the page
IF `Accept` header prefers `application/json`
     Output `Content-Type: application/json` header
     Output data in JSON format
ELSE
     Output `Content-Type: text/html` header
     Pass data through the template for the page
     Output template as HTML
```

And you would use `students.php` in the URL instead of `students` (or you would make `students` resolve to the PHP code you wanted to run instead).

Since you are using raw XMLHttpRequest, you will need to use `setRequestHeader` to set the Accept header. You are using jQuery though, so you could just use `$.ajax` and pass it `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: Just to clarify, how do applications such as [this](https://play.google.com/store) do the job? As you'll notice as you go through the application the URL changes and if you refresh it takes you straight to that page again

Comment: @BleedObsidian — Err. The way I said in the answer. You can tell because the page you gave as an example works if you turn JavaScript off.

Comment: How can I make my urls appear like example.com/students not example.com#!students

Comment: Then you do what I said in the answer, including the section I put in parentheses in the penultimate paragraph (which you could do by moving `students.php` to `students/index.php`).